# Sorting Array values in Dictionary of Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a .plist file with root dictionary and loading keys of letters as:

```
["A": ["AXB", "ACD", "ABC"], ... ]
```

It would be right by:

```
["A": ["ABC", "ACD", "AXB"], ... ]
```

Then, I wanna sort this array's itens of the A index. So, I tried do thus:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var musicalGroups : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
var keysOfMusicalGroups : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let path = bundle.path(forResource: "bandas", ofType: "plist")
    musicalGroups = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    keysOfMusicalGroups = NSMutableArray(array: musicalGroups.allKeys)
    keysOfMusicalGroups.sort(using: NSSelectorFromString("compare:"))

}
```

And I got just the keys of Dictionary sorted using keysOfMusicalGroups.sort code

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code only sorts the keys. You need to sort each individual array in the main dictionary.

Comment: Why are you using `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc., instead of their Swift counterparts?

Comment: @NRitH  Yes, it is like I have learned to work with tableview indexed. I have implemented those methods .

Comment: @rmaddy ... yes, but how can I do it?

Comment: I am posting the repo link here.  https://github.com/gasparteixeira/TableViewIndexed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to sort your dictionary keys and append each value (array) sorted to the resulting array 2D:

```
let dict = ["A": ["Angra", "Aerosmith", "ACDC", "Avantasia"],"B": ["Barao Vermelho", "Bon Jovi", "Bee Gees"],"C": ["Cachorro Loco", "Coldplay", "Creed"] ]

let sortedArray2D = dict.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key }.map { $0.value.sorted() }

print(sortedArray2D)  // "[["ACDC", "Aerosmith", "Angra", "Avantasia"], ["Barao Vermelho", "Bee Gees", "Bon Jovi"], ["Cachorro Loco", "Coldplay", "Creed"]]\n"
```

Your final table view should look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var musicalGroups: [[String]] = []
    var musicalTitles: [String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bandas", ofType: "plist")!) as? [String: [String]] ?? [:]
        musicalTitles = dict.keys.sorted()
        musicalGroups = dict.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key }.map { $0.value.sorted() }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return musicalGroups[section].count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return musicalTitles[section]
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return musicalTitles.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "exemplo")
        cell.textLabel?.text = musicalGroups[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A more *performance-wise* answer, based on **@Leo-Dabus**'s, is:

```
let dict = ["A": ["Angra", "Aerosmith", "ACDC", "Avantasia"],"B": ["Barao Vermelho", "Bon Jovi", "Bee Gees"],"C": ["Cachorro Loco", "Coldplay", "Creed"] ]

let sortedArray2D: [[String]] = dict.keys.sorted().map{ dict[$0]!.sorted() }

print(sortedArray2D)  // "[["ACDC", "Aerosmith", "Angra", "Avantasia"], ["Barao Vermelho", "Bee Gees", "Bon Jovi"], ["Cachorro Loco", "Coldplay", "Creed"]]\n"
```

This performs better because the compiler now knows that `sortedArray2D` has the same size as `dict`.

Also, this way `sortedArray2D` is a constant (`let`), and not a `var` anymore (allowing even further performance enhancements).

Comment: How does the compiler know that `map` returns a same size array? Is it documented somewhere that the swift compiler has special optimizations around `map`?

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html . In short: The ``map`` method takes a closure as its only argument.  The closure is called once for each item in the array, and returns an alternative mapped value (possibly of some other type) for that item. In conclusion: by using ``map``, we give the compiler more information of what the new array is going to be. Allowing it to allocate the right memory size (and probably something else that I'm not aware of).

Comment: The problem is that `map` internally likely uses a `var` and calls to `append` to create the new array, so while it might seem like an optimization, it's really just the same procedure wrapped in a function, except with the overhead of a method call and repeated closure invocations. So one could argue that it's actually less performant.

Comment: If we don't tell the compiler what the size of the new array is going to be, the program will need to allocate new memory from time to time (when we call ``append``). By using ``map``, the compiler knows what the new array size is going to be, removing the memory allocation overhead.

Comment: @PatrickGoley, go ahead, try it yourself: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57da4349f623dd089776d5c3 , in my tests, ``map`` is at least 2 times faster than the ``for``/``append`` alternative.

Comment: Well, I can't argue with that :) Very interesting. I'm still wondering how the compiler knows that map returns a same size array. Either it has special knowledge of the map function and assumes this, or it does analysis on the loop inside of map and optimizes it. I would expect though that this would also optimize the for loop that you wrote. Thanks for the example!

Comment: One thing to note is the performance is consistently much closer if you use a for in loop instead of the `forEach` function as in your example. Also, the answer you based this on additionally builds an array of `musicalTitles` in the loop. So your code is not equivalent and would require two `map`s to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: ``map`` always returns an array of the same size of the array it is called on. If you want to know more about ``map`` and other awesome Swift constructs (such as ``reduce``, ``flatmap``) I highly recommend this article by Benedikt Terhechte https://appventure.me/2015/11/30/reduce-all-the-things/ (a bit long but really, really worth to read)

Comment: The example was just to show you the difference between ``forEach`` and ``map``. It has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: regarding different loops (``for``, ``forEach`` ``while`` etc), the performance varies a lot based on what's inside the loop itself. Please see my comment here: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/643#issuecomment-170012966

Comment: Hi guys. I appreciated your interact about my doubt and foreach and map. I solved it based on @Leo-Dabus's answer! Thank  you all